# AWS ECR - Getting an image's age

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

Is there a way to find the age of a Docker image pushed to AWS ECR?

When I ask for the image manifest with `aws ecr batch-get-image --repository some/repo --image-ids "imageDigest=sha256:abcdef..."` then it returns the AWS reply with the embedded manifest. Sample output

```
{
  "images": [
     {
        "registryId": "1234",
        "imageId": {
          "imageDigest": "sha256:abcdef...",
          "imageTag": "latest"
         }
      },
      "imageManifest": "<serialised JSON I'll paste below>"
      "repositoryName": "some/repo"
     }
    ],
   "failures": []
}
```

and the serialised JSON embedded in the AWS response looks along these lines:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 123456,
    "digest": "sha256:38f08cc551925935e235c5c94ab3fb89568bd286e3335aa2e05d7bd3ceee4574"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 573764,
      "digest": "sha256:06dde66f337b57adcfca48b87d126b99a249765ccf2e09964584befc2890ae79"
    }
  ]
}
```

there is no metadata that I can see indicating when this image was pushed to ECR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I did not have enough permissions (lacked *ecr:ListImages*) to use `aws ecr describe-images`. With appropriate permissions I can run that sub-command and see the `imagePushedAt`. E.g.

```
{
    "imageDetails": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:309b3ae71cf0780232cb013fb77507977625f8fe8cee868feca2649890ae073b",
            "repositoryName": "somerepo/someimage",
            "registryId": "12345",
            "imagePushedAt": 1485358557.0,
            "imageSizeInBytes": 8986900
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:036a5da0dd8ef4a949293818cb05d15aaa31f2e8d9f464f9376667be9919e646",
            "repositoryName": "somerepo/someimage",
            "registryId": "12345",
            "imagePushedAt": 1485362799.0,
            "imageSizeInBytes": 8986643
        },
  ... and so on ...
```